# Caliburn.Micro: Combobox is not populated

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, caliburn.micro

I have a WPF application with Caliburn.Micro. I am trying to populate a new combobox I just added, but it stays empty, though the other comboboxes on the same view are populated. I debuged, so I know that the GeorgaphyNames source collection in the ViewModel is populated correctly. Could you please help?

Here is my code:

Model:

```
public class GeographyName : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value) return;
            _name = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name);
        }
    }
  ...
}
```

View:

```
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Name="GeographyNames" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Name" SelectedItem="SelectedGeographyName" Style="{StaticResource DetailCombo}" />
```

ViewModel:

```
    private BindableCollection<GeographyName> _geographyNames;
    public BindableCollection<GeographyName> GeorgaphyNames
    {
        get { return _geographyNames; }
        private set
        {
            if (_geographyNames == value)
                return;
            _geographyNames = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => GeorgaphyNames);
        }
    }


    private GeographyName _selectedGeographyName;
    public GeographyName SelectedGeographyName
    {
        get { return _selectedGeographyName; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedGeographyName == value)
                return;
            _selectedGeographyName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedGeographyName);
            IsModified = true;
        }
    }
```

The combobox is populated on changing selection in another combobox:

```
    private Ldc _selectedLdc;
    public Ldc SelectedLdc
    {
        get { return _selectedLdc; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedLdc == value)
                return;
            _selectedLdc = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SelectedLdc);
            if (SelectedLdc != null)
            {
                GeorgaphyNames = GeographyName.GetData(SelectedLdc.LdcId);
            }
            IsModified = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Never worked with Caliburn.micro, but where exactly do you set your combo box ItemsSource?

Comment: It is a convention in Caliburn.Micro. If the BindableCollection's name is the same as the control's name, it is used as its ItemsSource.

Comment: Check the DataContext for the Combobox in question. Maybe its inside another element which has DataContext not set to your ViewModel.

Comment: I don't think so, because I have already other comboboxes next to this one, and they are populated OK. I don't see what the difference is...

Comment: I just edited the question to show how the source collection is populated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view model property is called `GeorgaphyNames` which is a typo.

Also, it's best to use `x:Name` in your view, not `Name`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! I was looking and looking... and still didn't noticed it!

Comment: Why is it best to use `x:Name` instead of `Name`?